# UI Back button Android

Tags: android

I have the following code to go back to the previous page in my app.

```
Button wback = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.wback);
wback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mpButtonClick.start();
        finish();   

    }
```

I have a sound playing for the button press as well.  However the button doesn't work and the app stays where it is, pretty much doesn't do anything.  I was getting an error before but this was due to an incorrect button name.

The previous page I am going back to is an activity, it is labelled the following in my Manifest:

```
<action android:name="com.shade.waz.CLEARSCREEN" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: put `mpButtonClick.start();` before `finish()`.

Comment: HI, I tried this but it didn't work, and error posted.

Comment: Show the code for the `onPause()` method of the durood.java class and tell us which is line 220

Comment: I have added the code for the onPause method

Comment: OK, but which line is line 220?

Comment: wback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, call `mpButtonClick.start();` and then `finish();`

Comment: you have something wrong in the onPause of your durood.java class.

Comment: Everything else is working perfectly, it's just the back button that is not doing anything

Comment: You were right! there was something wrong in the onPause method.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

That is becuase `finish();` will finish your activity and close it. If your previous page is a fragment then you should just pop the backstack to that page, otherwise you will need to provide more information.

Here is an example of popping the backstack:

```
FragmentManager ft = getFragmentManager();
    ft.popBackStack("splash", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: previous page is an activity

Comment: Oh ok, I am not as familiar with that. From my limited knowledge Waqas answer seems that it should work.